# Google Place Autocomplete API Showing Blank Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following script to show auto complete place API on my webpage, everything is working fine but map is not showing, i have tried multiple solutions but they won't help in any way here is my script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<script>
var map;
var marker;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos,
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {

  document.getElementById("location-text-box").value = str;
}


 function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Get GEOLOCATION
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude);

      map.setCenter(pos);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
       map: map,
        draggable: true
      });

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    //updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    //updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    //updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
   // alert("drag ended");
    //updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });



    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
      var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
      content: content
    };

    map.setCenter(options.position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: options.position,
     map: map,
      draggable: true
    });

    // Update current position info.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    //updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    //updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    //updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
   });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
   // alert("drag ended");
    //updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

    }


  // get places auto-complete when user type in location-text-box
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (
      document.getElementById('location-text-box'));


  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
    draggable: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon( /** @type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
  ].join(' ');
    }

  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

out put i'm getting is 
[image]

**html**

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
<input id="location-text-box"/>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show also the html code  not only the script .. (the script seems work)

Comment: [working fiddle (once an address is selected)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kbbxp2on/)

Comment: @scaisEdge: just update my question please check now

Comment: @geocodezip it's working fine separately, but i have a complete dashboard of user and that API should work there but it's not working there

Comment: For me too working fine then the problem is related to code or env  that we can't see or evaluate..

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: should i provide you the website credentials where I'm using that, it's working perfectly on separately page but when I'm using this with my web page map is not showing